# Fill in the missing values if rows in other columns are the same

Tags: r, excel, missing-data

I have a table which looks the following way:

| Name | Region | Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | US | 123 |
| Name1 | US |  |
| Name2 | US | 122 |
| Name3 | US | 124 |
| Name1 | UK |  |
| Name1 | UK | 135 |
| Name2 | UK | 140 |
| Name3 | US |  |

As you can see there are empty values in the ID column which I want to be filled with the values of other rows if the column Name and Region correspond. So it should look like this:

| Name | Region | Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | US | 123 |
| Name1 | US | 123 |
| Name2 | US | 122 |
| Name3 | US | 124 |
| Name1 | UK | 135 |
| Name1 | UK | 135 |
| Name2 | UK | 140 |
| Name3 | US |  |

Some of the columns will still be left empty but the majority will be fine. Is there a way to do so in R?
Maybe it will be easier to so in Excel even (Vlookup maybe I am not sure). Share if you have any ideas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of rows is important here Eg - Name3 US in row 4 and row 8 are not related and treated differently. We can create a new group using `consecutive_id` and then `fill` the `Id` values for each group.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(group_id = consecutive_id(Name, Region)) %>%
  group_by(group_id) %>%
  fill(Id, .direction = "downup") %>%
  ungroup

# A tibble: 8 × 4
#  Name  Region    Id group_id
#  <chr> <chr>  <int>    <int>
#1 Name1 US       123        1
#2 Name1 US       123        1
#3 Name2 US       122        2
#4 Name3 US       124        3
#5 Name1 UK       135        4
#6 Name1 UK       135        4
#7 Name2 UK       140        5
#8 Name3 US        NA        6
```

`group_id` column is just for explanation purposes on how groups are created, you may drop the column if you don't need it.

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("Name1", "Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name1", 
"Name1", "Name2", "Name3"), Region = c("US", "US", "US", "US", 
"UK", "UK", "UK", "US"), Id = c(123L, NA, 122L, 124L, NA, 135L, 
140L, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```